# How should I reduce the memory usage of a large cartesian product with repeating digits?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, python-itertools, cartesian-product

In Python3, given a list of numbers [1, 1, 2, 3] I am to return all permutations with repeating digits up to a certain length of numbers.  So we will say x = 3, meaning the result would be
1
11
111
112
113
.
.
3
33
312
321
333

I've reduced it down to list comprehension in hopes that it would solve the issue I'm having with memory consumption, but I haven't seen a notable increase.

What can I do to reduce the needed memory for a large input list (say, 9 elements)?

```py
return sum(sum(1 for _set in product(digits, repeat=i) if int(''.join(_set)) <= n) for i in range(1, len(str(n)) + 1))
```

Comment: Looks like you are summing over this final list that you obtain? Its in your best interest to elaborate and explain the actual problem you are trying to solve, which might have a more optimal solution than the one you are after

Answer (score 0):

python int takes the size of a long, in array you can use regular int

```
from array import array
import sys
a = [] #regular list
b = array('I') # int
c = array('B') # short, probably cant take too long numbers
for i in range(100):
    a.append(i)
    b.append(i)
    c.append(i)


#>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
#5496
#>>> sys.getsizeof(b)
#2592
#>>> sys.getsizeof(c)
#696
```

Comment: I should have used better wording.  I'm concerned with the length of the input list, not the number of digits per number.  I've updated my post to use better verbiage.